# Efficient way yo sink Pub/Sub messages to BigQuery using Cloud Functions

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

One of the recommended ways of using Cloud Functions is to invoke them with Pub/Sub Push subscription to write Pub/Sub messages to BigQuery. I have very tiny messages and I have a lot of them.

I'm paying around ~$80 for 60.000.000 messages written to GBQ. The configuration of my GCF is 128 MB, 1 sec timeout.

Source code:

```js
exports['write-to-gbq'] = async (event, context) => {
  const message = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(event.data, 'base64').toString())
  const dataset = bigquery.dataset('dataset')
  const table = dataset.table('table')
  await table.insert({...message, created_at: new BigQueryDatetime(String(new Date().toISOString()))})
};
```

Is there a way cut the cost 10+ folds? Compute Engine instance seems to be way less expensive, but maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Look at your bill.  How are the costs broken down (percentages).  How much is BQ, how much is Pub/Sub etc?  What are your functional requirements ... for example ... would it be acceptable to have latency such that inserts were batched and not available in BQ as soon as possible?

Comment: The $80 is only for Cloud Function. GBQ bill is just $8 and it hardly related to this sink. It's more fore querying I guess. Latency up to a few hours is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since August 2022, you can use BigQuery Subscription to write pubsub messages into BQ https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/bigquery

You can find announcement here https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/pub-sub-launches-direct-path-to-bigquery-for-streaming-analytics

Answer (score 3):

You can use Cloud Run. You can trigger it with a PubSub push subscription, but you can process several concurrent message on the same instance, compared to Cloud Functions with accept only 1 message at a time.

And you are charged for the running time of your instance (charged on CPU time and Memory time). I wrote (a quite old and slightly out of date) [article on that](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-vs-cloud-functions-whats-the-lowest-cost-728d59345a2e).

Now you can have up to 250 concurrent request in GA and up to 1000 concurrent request in Preview per instance. You can speed up your process and decrease your costs.

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware of that method. I just thought that GCFs are optimized for this kind of task.

Comment: It's the purpose of GCF (and FaaS generally): Glue components together. However, when the volume because huge, other products are better than others, because it's not only GLUE, it's a real pipeline!

Comment: Maybe you are right. Well, in that case you should probably suggest Compute Engine Preemptible instances, not Cloud Run.

Comment: If you use Compute Engine (or GKE Autopilot) for long running operation, prefer PubSub pulling instead of Push operation. It's more efficient in term of bandwidth, throughput and processing

Answer (score 0):

**You may use a dataflow template for this purpose as shown below screenshot**

[image]

Comment: I've tried it once and it seems way more complex and expensive. Also, I transform the input as you can see, I add "created_at" property.